# registerMultiTask.js in grunt-horde

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to configure [grunt-horde](https://github.com/codeactual/grunt-horde) so that I can have multiple builds all using a centrally managed task configuration.

The documentation provides the following example of a `registerMultiTasks.js` file, but I can't get it to work

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var myMultiTask = require('./multi-tasks/secret-sauce.js');

    return {
        myMultiTask: ['some description', myMultiTask]
    };
};
```

Even if I replace their example with something more simple:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    return {
        demo: ['Demo', function() {
            console.info('hello');
        }]
    };
};
```

When I run `grunt demo:test` the output is:

```
Running "demo:test" (demo) task
Verifying property demo.test exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "demo.test" missing. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

When I run `grunt --help` the `demo` task shows up in the list.  Thinking about the warning message I've also tried the following, but again with no luck.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    return {
        demo: ['Demo', function(){
            return {test: function(){console.info('hello');}};
        }]
    };
};
```

...what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - you need to define the configuration for each target of the multitasks:

`initConfig/demo.js`

```
module.exports = function() {
    'use strict';

    return {
        test: {
            foo: 'bar'
        }
    };
};
```

You can then access this configuration data and the target from within the multitask function:

`registerMultiTask.js`

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    return {
        demo: ['Demo', function() {
            grunt.log.writeln('target: ' + this.target);
            grunt.log.writeln('foo: ' + this.data.foo);
        }]
    };
};
```